# Completely lost with Blackberry JDE for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, jde

I'm serious.  I installed the Blackberry web developer thing for eclipse (being stupid, and not seeing the 'web' part).  Then, when I realized my mistake, I went and got the JDE for Eclipse. I went through the install process....open up Eclipse...and I'm lost.  I don't know how to run code...or the simulator, or anything.

All the tutorials I'm finding are referencing an older "beta" version of the Eclipse plugin, which apparently had a "Blackberry" menu option. I'm not seeing that.

I found some sample code, which gives the helpful instructions:

"1. Extract HelloWorld_incomplete.zip
2.  In the IDE, open the helloworld.jdw workspace
3.  Open the helloworld.java source file.
"

...I've never seen a .jdw file before. If I try opening it in Eclipse, I get a not-very-useful text file. Since they say it's a workspace, I try the "Switch Workspace" option in Eclipse, which lets me pick a folder, rather than a file.

I'm pretty sure "Import Project" isn't right, either.

So, I figure I'll deal with that later, so I open up the source code (a standard .java file, with a main, etc). I try running it, but it asks for an Ant build file.

I can run standard Java files just fine (that is, I know Java is in my path).

I don't know if maybe I don't have the Blackberry part right...or if it's on the eclipse side where I'm failing.

Does anyone have any ideas?

-Jenny

Edit: Just to be sure, I tried downloading the plugin through eclipse with their provided link (http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate), but eclipse says that it got a .jar file when it was expecting a .zip file, and so it errored. Can you even unzip a jar file (like Eclipse is trying to do?)

Comment: You say you don't see the blackberry menu between "Run" and "Window". If you go to File->New->Project, do you see "Blackberry" under the list of project types?

Comment: Nope, not at all.  I can, however, run any file as a "Blackberry Web", from my first (mistake) install.

Comment: Not that it actually does anything to my java files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the wrong package.

I installed it yesterday from the "Download Now" button at http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaeclipseplug.jsp
and it had both the menu option and the Blackberry project type.

It should have an installer if you get the correct one. I would post a direct link, but RIM likes to ask for your info before allowing the download.

Try installing it to a different directory and using a new workspace. It could be that the old install is interfering somehow.

-Hope that helps

Comment: Well, I did get that installer originally, but I'll try your advice of using a new workspace.

Comment: It wants to install to the eclipse directory, so I don't think I even have the option of installing to a different directory... Is it possible I have the wrong version of Eclipse? The BB website says it works with 3.4.0 and 3.4.1, while I have 3.4.2 .  I assumed that it would work for 3.4.0 and higher, but maybe I was wrong?

Comment: In step 3 of the install process, "Choose install folder", choose an new, empty directory. The installer will go ahead and give you the optimal version of eclipse with no separate download required.

Comment: That did it...must have been eclipse after all. Thanks for your help! Now at least I have a place to start from!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know step by step to install the jde plugin in eclipse you can visit http://learn.virtue-software.com/2011/05/quick-start-creating-blackberry-application-with-eclipse/